# Does Mgo cache connection strings?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, compose-db

My Go application has been connecting to a MongoDB (hosted on Compose.io) using MGO with no issues.

Today I decided to delete this database and add a different one (again using Compose). I updated the connection string.

So I connect using:

```
db, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://<username>:<password>@dogen.mongohq.com:10048/db-name")
```

with the username and password in place.

Strangely, the application still appears to connect to the old database. I know this because I printed the `err` message out which told me: **not authorized for query on my-old-db-name** after I tried to perform a query.

I have run `go install` to compile again but still no luck.

Comment: Yeah I thought that - how do I overcome this issue?

Comment: The database does have a new name - a different name.

Comment: Glad you found a solution, I have learn new thing today too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, mgo does not cache the connection strings you give to the [mgo.Dial](http://gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Dial) function. It's not even clear to me what that would mean? Using an incorrect database name after you explicitly asked it to connect to a different database would be a serious bug, rather than caching.

As for your problem, are you sure you are not referring to the old database name inside your own code? The Dial function is not the only way to specify database names (hint: [session.DB](http://gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.DB))

Comment: Oh you're right - I forgot about the extra reference to the DB name. That's the issue.